# Percentage related question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving following question:

Last year Elaine spent 20% of her annual earnings on rent. This
year she earned 15% more than last year and she spent 30% of
her annual earnings on rent. The amount she spent on rent this
year is what percent of the amount spent on rent last year?

The answer that I found was 172%. But that book had 170% as the answer.

Tell me what am I doing wrong?

if x is her annual earning in year 1. the rent in year 1 will be 0.2x

income in year 2 is 1.15x then rent in year 2 will be 0.3 * 1.15x = 0.345x

and (0.345x / 0.2x)* 100 = 172.5 %

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from what I see there is no problem with your answer.

Comment: Then why my answer is different?

Comment: what type of assignment were you doing?

Comment: It is a multiple choice question.

Comment: there you go. Is there any other option closer to 172.5%?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the book has done an approximation (a wrong one ) of 0.345 to 0.34 (truncated 3rd digit ). That approximation will give you 170% .But your answer is exact .

Comment: thanks for clarification :)